# convert String of length 24 to byte array of length 4 bytes

Tags: java

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
     Date localRecvTime = new Date();           
     DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
     converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));           
     String ConvertedDate =converter.format(localRecvTime);
     System.out.println(ConvertedDate.length());
     //above statement will print 24

     byte[] dateInBytes=ConvertedDate.getBytes();
     System.out.println(dateInBytes.length);
     //above statement will also print 24       

    }
```

The above code works fine.
But i want to limit the size of byte `array(ie. byte[] dateInBytes)` to 4 bytes according to my requirements.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to fit 24 bytes of information into 4 bytes? or you only want 4 bytes of that information?

Comment: @ TheMerovingian i want to fit 24 byte string into 4 byte array

Comment: actually i want to save date of format(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z') into 4 byte array

Comment: For me it's like asking if a pig can fly on the example of tornado...
You can convert String represanting date to long, but it has nothing to do with the title of your question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't convert it into a string in the first place. You've got a `Date`, which is effectively a 64-bit value: the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch of January 1st 1970 at midnight, UTC.

If you've only got 4 bytes available, you need a 32-bit value. If you divide the milliseconds by 1000, you'll get the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch... and that gives you enough range to last until 2038. You could extend that range significantly further by changing the epoch, effectively. If you use an epoch of 2075, you should be able to store values from about 2010 to 2140. You'll still only be storing the value to a second granularity, of course.

Alternatively, you could stick with milliseconds as granularity, but reduce the range. Unfortunately it would reduce the range very significantly - to about 48 days. Unless you're expecting values in a *very* tight range, that's probably not an option for you.

Once you've worked out your 32-bit representation, there are various ways of converting that into a byte array, including using `DataOutputStream`. (If the goal is to write the value to a stream anyway, don't bother with the intermediate byte array.)

Answer (score -1):

Ummm ... no, it is not possible to put 24 bytes into 4 bytes

Nor is it possible to put 24 characters into 4 bytes either (as characters always at least as large as a byte).

But I think Jon got it right: the number of seconds since 1970 will fit in 4 bytes.

Comment: +1 to compensate the no reason downvote, the answer is acutally right.